# When I create an index in MariaDB/MySQL with a comment attached to it, where is that comment stored?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

I've looked through `information_schema` and can't find these comments anywhere?

I'm trying to use `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INDEX_STATISTICS` as a basis for finding unused/redundant indexes, and figured it'd be a lot more useful if I could see the comments I've created alongside the indexes by joining `INDEX_STATISTICS` to another table, but all I can find is `INNODB_SYS_INDEXES` and it doesn't have the comment field in there.

Are they only saved in the DDL, and as such not able to be returned in such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Comment attribute from the view `information_schema.STATISTICS`, by accessing `INDEX_COMMENT` field. From MySQL [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/statistics-table.html):

> **INDEX_COMMENT**
>
> Any comment provided for the index with a COMMENT attribute when the
>   index was created.

Try the following:

```
SELECT INDEX_SCHEMA, INDEX_NAME, INDEX_COMMENT 
FROM information_schema.STATISTICS
```

Comment: Huh, thank you.  I hadn't looked in that table and never would have guessed from its name!